# Is it possible to login to Facebook From Facebook messenger?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, account-recovery

Someone is logged out of Facebook and can't access it, long story, but he's still logged in to messenger.

Is it possible to log in to Facebook mobile app, by using Facebook's messenger session, without entering his password, so that he can change it?

Because back when I used Facebook, it was possible for me to login to messenger automatically without using a password if i'm logged in to Facebook, I want to know if the opposite is also true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible. You will have to login again using the main Facebook app.